GitLab Terraform report fails to generate
I am currently creating a repository in GitLab to provide infrastructure with Terraform and deploy via CI/CD. I am following the approach of managing several environments in the repository, as described here in the example here
When creating a merge request the pipeline runs smoothly without any errors but the terraform plan widget in the merge request overview fails to generate the report
report fails to load:

This is the code of my build stage:
.build:
  extends: .before_script_template
  stage: build
  script:
    # - jq --version
    - terraform plan -out="plan.tfplan"
    - terraform show -json $PLAN | jq -r '([.resource_changes[]?.change.actions?]|flatten)|{\"create\":(map(select(.==\"create\"))|length),\"update\":(map(select(.==\"update\"))|length),\"delete\":(map(select(.==\"delete\"))|length)}' > $PLAN_JSON
  artifacts:
    name: plan
    paths:
      - ${TF_ROOT}/$PLAN
      - ${TF_ROOT}/$PLAN_JSON
    reports:
      terraform: ${TF_ROOT}/$PLAN_JSON

The jq command is working and generates a plan.json file with the following content
{
  "create": 1,
  "update": 0,
  "delete": 0
}

As far as I know this is the expected output for the terraform report to show in the merge request. The upload of the report also seems to work. This is what the logs show:
Terraform used the selected providers to generate the following execution
plan. Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  + create
Terraform will perform the following actions:
  # azurerm_resource_group.lab-rg-dev-cicd will be created
  + resource "azurerm_resource_group" "lab-rg-dev-cicd" {
      + id       = (known after apply)
      + location = "westeurope"
      + name     = "rg-dev-cicd"
    }
Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.
─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Saved the plan to: plan.tfplan
To perform exactly these actions, run the following command to apply:
    terraform apply "plan.tfplan"
$ terraform show -json $PLAN | jq -r '([.resource_changes[]?.change.actions?]|flatten)|{\"create\":(map(select(.==\"create\"))|length),\"update\":(map(select(.==\"update\"))|length),\"delete\":(map(select(.==\"delete\"))|length)}' > $PLAN_JSON
Saving cache for successful job
00:06
Version:      14.3.2
Git revision: e0218c92
Git branch:   14-3-stable
GO version:   go1.13.8
Built:        2021-09-30T16:11:30+0000
OS/Arch:      windows/amd64
Creating cache ./environments/dev-non_protected...
Runtime platform                                    arch=amd64 os=windows pid=6060 revision=e0218c92 version=14.3.2
./environments/dev/.terraform/: found 9 matching files and directories 
No URL provided, cache will be not uploaded to shared cache server. Cache will be stored only locally. 
Created cache
Uploading artifacts for successful job
00:02
Version:      14.3.2
Git revision: e0218c92
Git branch:   14-3-stable
GO version:   go1.13.8
Built:        2021-09-30T16:11:30+0000
OS/Arch:      windows/amd64
Uploading artifacts...
Runtime platform                                    arch=amd64 os=windows pid=7704 revision=e0218c92 version=14.3.2
./environments/dev/plan.tfplan: found 1 matching files and directories 
./environments/dev/plan.json: found 1 matching files and directories 
Uploading artifacts as "archive" to coordinator... ok  id=162303037 responseStatus=201 Created token=glcbt-64
Version:      14.3.2
Git revision: e0218c92
Git branch:   14-3-stable
GO version:   go1.13.8
Built:        2021-09-30T16:11:30+0000
OS/Arch:      windows/amd64
Uploading artifacts...
Runtime platform                                    arch=amd64 os=windows pid=7816 revision=e0218c92 version=14.3.2
./environments/dev/plan.json: found 1 matching files and directories 
Uploading artifacts as "terraform" to coordinator... ok  id=162303037 responseStatus=201 Created token=glcbt-64
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:00
Job succeeded

I can find the uploaded artifacts in the GitLab portal. So what am I missing?

The artifacts portion of the code is different from the example you provided... gitlab offers support, I think they will be the best equip to help:
https://about.gitlab.com/support/

Yes, I tried different solutions in the artifact section. Once with providing the "name", once without. Also providing the path to both plan files generated or only one/none of them. There was no difference in the outcome.
